# Vuejs sort and filter data

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js

i'm trying make sorting and filters for my data. I have some cards from API.
For sorting i have few issues ( sort card by price, sort by time, etc. )
The default sort is sort by price, it's enabled.

Filters are inputs that should show show/hide my cards ( example: range of min-prices and max-prices)

I've already done my filters, but when i'm trying to sort items by time, filter's v-show logic saved from previous sorting ( sort by price )

Cards are coming from mounted() axios responce

**Result.vue**

**Buttons for sort**

```
<div class="sort-btn down" v-bind:class="{ activesort: activesort }" 
    v-on:click='changeSort'>By Price
</div>
<div class="sort-btn down" v-bind:class="{ activesort: !activesort }" 
    v-on:click='changeSort'>By Time
</div>
```

**Card component**

```
<card :item="item" v-for="(item, index) in filteredAndSortedData"
:key="index"></card>
```

**JS**

```
computed: {
            filteredAndSortedData() {
                let result = this.cards;
                if(this.orderByTime){
                    return result.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.info.time - b.info.time;
                    });
                } else {
                    return result.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.price - b.price;
                    });
                }

            }
        }

data() {
    return {
        activesort: true,
        orderByTime: false,
        showFilters: false,
    }
},

methods: {
    changeSort: function () {
        this.activesort = !this.activesort;
        this.orderByTime = !this.orderByTime;
    },
}
```

**Card.vue**

```
<div class="card-wrapper" v-bind:class="{'has-label': hasLabel}" v-show="showCard">
    <div>{{item.price}}</div>
    <div>{{item.time}}</div>
</div>

data () {
    return {
        showCard: true,
    }
},

methods: {
    changeFilter() {
        if(some logic when clicking input){
            this.showCard = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem is: i have two sorting buttons, few filters buttons.
When i'm trying to change sorting and then use filters button, it works correct.
But when i'm trying to filter first and then change sorting, i get sorted cards, but filters work incorrect

Also i set up a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wLtk6zn/) to represent what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add:

`result = result.filter(todo => todo.price >= this.price);`

before sorting? Your watcher and `show` property in your todos are not necessary too.

https://jsfiddle.net/3wLtk6zn/4/

Edit: if you want to do it your way with a watcher, it's possible too:
https://jsfiddle.net/3wLtk6zn/8/

The reason why your code didn't work is that each time your `todos` property is recomputed you set your `result` to array with all items and your watcher only filters your result when you change the price, so changing sorting method "unfilters" the array. This can be fixed by moving `result` outside your computed property to `data`.

Comment: This can be fixed by moving result outside your computed property to data. I can't move it to data, cause result is API response in my mounted lifehook, and when page render result will be empty, and i got errors